chrome not able to remote in jupyter notebook but safari works
jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8899 --ip=0.0.0.0 --NotebookApp.token='' --NotebookApp.password='' --NotebookApp.allow_remote_access=True 


I can use a mac with safari to remote in this server without any problem
however chrome and firefox doens't work

anyone know how to fix it?
methods tried:

uninstalled miniconda and jupyter
I even uninstalled and reinstalled ubuntu.
uninstalled and reinstalled chrome on mac


